# ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients only when running test with gradle

Tags: java, spring, gradle, testing

I have a project and tried to include an external jar which is built with dependencies. This jar file is including below as depenencies

```
    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
        <version>1.7</version>
    </dependency>       
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-compress</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
    </dependency>
            
</dependencies>
```

The jar file is included to the project as below

```
dependencies {
    implementation files('libs/xxxx-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar')
```

It works fine when run as an application, but ClassNotFoundException is occurred when running a testing with gradle

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:132)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:124)
    ...
            Caused by:
                java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients
                    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
                    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
                    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
                    ... 117 more
```

If I add a dependencies as testImplementation 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.+' then running a test on test-explore in VS Code works, but running test with gradle still make an exception on runtime

```
            java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE
                at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.<clinit>(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:151)
```

Anyone have any idea what I need to do?

Comment: It looks like you are having different versions of httpclient on your classpath. If your jar-with-deps is build correctly it should not be necessary to add httpclient as test dependency explicitly. You could try (as intermediate step) to set the test dependency to the same version as in the jar.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, @DrHopfen.
I tried set the same version of the jar-with-deps which is httpclient 4.2.6, but it still make an exception - `NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/impl/client/HttpClients`